# Updating array with data from a checked box

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add data to my array from a checked box. The checked box outputs on when is ticked and I need it to output 1 instead, and 0 when unticked. I have added the code

```
'allow_email' => ($_POST['allow_email'] == 'on') ? 1 : 0);
```

But it isn't liking it and produces an error. Is there another way to write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'allow_email' => ($_POST['allow_email']) ? 1 : 0));` should work. The reasoning being that if the box is not checked, it won't even show up in the list of POST variables, thus creating a false expression.

Answer (score 0):

you have a missing bracket

```
'allow_email' => ((@$_POST['allow_email'] == 'on') ? 1 : 0);
```

also suppress your POST incase its empty